# Can you convert a scalar into an arbitrary length array in excel

Tags: excel

The reason I'm doing this is so I don't have to use matrix multiplication and can use sumproduct instead.  I can do it with matrix multiplication, but I'd rather not have the overhead of explaining what that is and how to do it to my colleagues.  I need to apply a scalar to two arrays that I'm applying a sumproduct against.  The problem is that since the scalar is length 1, it breaks the sumproduct formula.
Here is what the formula looks like:

```
=sumproduct(1/sumif(conditionals), array 2, array 3)
```

What I would like to do is scale the first array, which is my scalar, based on the size of the other 2 arrays.  I have tried this, which I figured wouldn't work, but it should get the idea of what I'm trying to accomplish across:

```
=sumproduct(rept(1/sumif(conditionals),count(array 2)), array 2, array 3)
```

The problem here is that the rept function returns a string, which I'm unable to use round() or any other formulas I can think of to make into an 1xN array of that scalar.  I should note I'm not trying to cast the variable necessarily, but if there is a way to do that it would likely solve the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: That won't work work on an array.

Comment: You said, 'rept function returns a string'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
=sumproduct((1/sumif(conditionals))*'array 2'*'array 3')
```

In addition, wouldn't that be mathematically the same as

```
=(1/sumif(conditionals))*sumproduct('array 2','array 3')
```

Comment: Doh... this indeed works better and is easier to interpret. Multiplying by a scalar in the body of the `SUMPRODUCT()` function multiplies the entire array in it. This shows the prefered modus of using `SUMPRODUCT()`: multiply the arrays `SUMPRODUCT(ary1 * ary2 * ary3)` (which operates as a kind of AND operator), rather than using the comma-operated function `SUMPRODUCT(ary1, ary2, ary3)`.

Comment: Thanks, you got it.  I ended up realizing the 2nd one a bit after I posted the question.

Answer (score 1):

The following formula should solve your problem:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
            ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & COUNT(array 2))) ^ 0 / SUMIF(conditionals),
            array 2,
            array 3
           )
```

This works as follows:

First obtain the number of elements of array 2:

```
COUNT(array 2)
```

Then convert it into a 'virtual' range reference (only rows):

```
INDIRECT("1:" & COUNT(array 2))
```

Then determine the row numbers from this virtual range reference, the result of which is `{1,2,...,COUNT}`:

```
ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & COUNT(array 2)))
```

Finally, convert the row number by raising to the power 0:

```
ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & COUNT(array 2))) ^ 0
```

This gives you the desired array `{1,1,...,1}` with `COUNT` elements, which can be used in the `SUMPRODUCT()` function.